# Подстановка n-ого порядка

Tags: алгоритм, pascal

Здравствуйте, не могу понять как решать данную задачу, пожалуйста, кто может, приведите код с пояснениями... Заранее благодарен.

Задача:

С клавиатуры вводится число n - порядок подстановки, и затем таблица из двух строк. Отпределите является ли эта таблица подстановкой n-ого порядка.

```
Пример:  
5  
1 2 3 4 2  
4 2 1 3 5    
NO  

5  
1 5 3 4 2  
4 7 1 3 5   
NO  

4  
3 2 1 4  
4 2 1 3  
YES  

5   
1 2 3 4  
4 2 1 3  
NO  

5  
1 5 3 4 2  
4 3 5 3 5  
NO  

5  
1 5 3 4 2  
4 2 1 3 5  
YES
```

Вот моё решение(выводить ошибку - помогите):

```
type  
  DinArr = array of longint;  
function Sort(arr: DinArr): DinArr;     
var  
  i, j: longint;  
  b: word;  
begin  
  for i:= 1 to length(arr)-1 do  
    begin  
      for j:= 1 to length(arr)-i do  
        begin  
          if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) then  
            begin  
              b:= arr[j];  
              arr[j]:= arr[j+1];  
              arr[j+1]:= b;  
            end;  
        end;  
    end;  
  Sort:= arr;  
end;  

var
  a, b: DinArr;
  a2, b2: DinArr;
  i, j, n: longint;
begin
  readln(n);
  setlength(a, 1);
  setlength(b, 1);
  for i:= 1 to length(a) do
    begin
      setlength(a, length(a)+1);
      readln(a[i]);
    end;
  for i:= 1 to length(b) do
    begin
      setlength(b, length(b)+1);
      readln(b[i]);
    end;
  setlength(a2, 100);
  setlength(b2, 100);
  a2:= Sort(a);
  b2:= Sort(b);
  for i:= 1 to length(a) do
    begin
      if (a2[i] <> b2[i]) then
        begin
          writeln('NO');
          exit;
        end;
    end;
  writeln('YES');
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

А всё просто. А программирование - это искусство. А искусство - это МАТАН!
Вообщем читаем определение:

> Определение 1.14. Подстановкой (перестановкой) множества N{1,2,..n}, состоящего из n первых натуральных чисел, называется взаимно-однозначное отображение множества N на себя.

Опача! Проверяем по нашим примерам:

```
5
 1 2 3 4 2
 4 2 1 3 5 
 NO
```

Как видно из примера, вверху 2 двойки, а внизу - одна О_О, значит ответ NEIN(нем. нет)

```
4
 3 2 1 4
 4 2 1 3
 YES
```

А вот тут всё оки-доки. Ну, в общем, код можно записать вот так (совершенный код):
http://paste.org.ru/?ruv214
Писал вручную, не компилировал, но работать должно. В общем, суть такова, просто есть массив, это будет массив вхождений различных чисел в множество, ну, вот индексы масива - это и есть все различные числа, которые разрешается вводить. Ну, вот вводим и числа и под соответсвующими индексами увеличиваем элементы массива. А когда вводим вторую строку, мы точно также уменьшаем и если массив будет в конце концов таким, как в начале (по умолчанию нулевым), то всё хорошо. Ответ да, иначе нет.

Comment: Судя по четвертому примеру,
надо еще проверять, что количество чисел правильное.

Comment: Как бы мой код это демонстрирует.

Comment: Как бы ваш код невозможно читать.

Comment: Умейте откидывать лишнее. Там всё понятно, если не смотреть на кучи writeln'ов
Это же программа на полстранички, а не какой-нибуть не документированный проект.
http://paste.org.ru/?ou318v без комментариев

Comment: А если использовать динамические массивы(FreePascal)? просто длина строки вводится не должна, я тут написал код, но ошибка вылезает, может поможете разобраться?